# Error on createTextNode MATLAB 2015b XMLUtils

Tags: xml, matlab, writexml

I write some data into a XML-file:

```
   [FileName,PathName] = uiputfile('*.xml','Select the XML file');
   if length(FileName) > 3
        completePath = [PathName FileName];
        % Create the DOM-Object
        docNode = com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.createDocument('docRootNode');
        docRootNode = docNode.getDocumentElement;
        docRootNode.setAttribute('version','2.0');
        mElement = docNode.createElement('Data1'); 
        docRootNode.appendChild(mElement)
        fields = fieldnames(struct1);
        for i = 1:numel(fields)
            thisElement = docNode.createElement(fields{i});
            thisElement.appendChild... 
            (docNode.createTextNode(struct1.(fields{i}))); %NO ERROR
            mElement.appendChild(thisElement);
        end
        rElement = docNode.createElement('Data2'); 
        docRootNode.appendChild(rElement)
        fields = fieldnames(struct2);
        for i = 1:numel(fields)
            thisElement = docNode.createElement(fields{i});
            thisElement.appendChild... 
            (docNode.createTextNode(struct2.(fields{i}))); %ERROR
            rElement.appendChild(thisElement); 
        end
    xmlwrite(completePath, docNode);
    end
```

Last week it worked without any problems, but since today I get this error in the line tagged with `%ERROR` running my code:

> No method 'createTextNode' with matching signature found for class 'org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl'.

I did not find any solution searching the internet (a problem might be that I am no admin on my PC). 
I also do not understand, why I got no error in the upper part (`%NO ERROR`)

Comment: yes, because createTextNode is not a class in org.apache, you want to use com.mathworks.xml.createDocument.createTextNode; ALSO I noticed that you set your root element to 'docRootNode' and then immediately set that into docNode.getDocumentElement. you might want to fix this first.

Comment: @GameOfThrows I understand the problem, but I don't really see how to fix it. Why does matlab want to use 'org.apache...' although my docNode is 'com.mathworks...' 
I changed the other point you mentioned ;).

Comment: It will automatically look into other libraries if it did not find it on your specified path, it is part of a resolving process. Try putting in the full path when you call the function createTextNode and see what happens, if it still outputs this error, then you will need to contact Matlab support.

Comment: I still get this error, so I will contact Matlab support. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved with the support of MATLAB:
 The only problem in my program was, that `struct2` contained integer values.
`struct1` contained only string-values, so there was no problem.
I use `num2str` to convert the numeric values now and have no problem anymore ;).